# rerun shell script only from failed command

Tags: bash, shell

I've bash script written to read each line of a file which has commands and execute them one by one and stops when a command fails.

```
while read -r line
do
$line || exit 1
done< /root/ansi-pb/sample.txt
```

sample.txt has following commands

```
echo "hello world"
free -m
mvn -version
date
echo "bye"
```

I want to improvise this script, so If I encounter any failed command I would correct it in text file and when I rerun the script it should start only from failed command but not from the beginning

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Ouch. This is Ansible anti pattern usage.

Comment: this is a weird way of trying to use ansible, and not for something it was designed for.

Comment: Don't use stderr contents to recognize failures. This is what exit status exists for; use it. And I agree with other commenters that ansible is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: ...if you want to have a shell function that wraps a command, writing a piece of status to disk indicating which step in a multi-step task we're on, skipping the step if it's too early, etc., then you can do that -- but as a *shell function*; ansible is adding a huge amount of unnecessary and unhelpful complexity and overhead.

Comment: If what I described above *is* your end goal, ask about that end goal as a separate question, `@`-notify me there, and I'd be glad to help you with it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank You.! for your suggestion but what would be best possible way to achieve the above scenario.

First read all commands in a text file,
execute them one by one,
abort if any command fails to execute properly,
run the script from where it was aborted (instead of executing from first again)

Comment: That's a good question, but it should be a **question**, not a comment. If you don't have any answers for this as-currently-asked you can edit it in a way that changes its meaning -- once you have an answer, then edits should only be clarification and not change, so if that happens you'd want to ask in a separate question.

Comment: @hruday, ...to be clear, I'm happy to help, but what you're asking for isn't a good fit for the comments fields, and if I added something as an answer that didn't talk about ansible to this question (as it's presently posed and worded, asking very specifically about ansible alone), I'd be providing an off-topic answer and breaking site rules myself.

Comment: @Charles Duffy
Plz help with this scenario.